# CMake cannot find requested Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Now that I've looked through other peoples solutions for several hours and could not find quite the right answer for my problem I would like to bring my specific problem to you. :)

I am trying to build vsomeip with CMake. For that I previously built boost 1.55, however, I get the following errors in CMake:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visua Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Setting build type to 'RelWithDebInfo' as none was specified.
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2025 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_55_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

      boost_system
      boost_thread
      boost_log

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)


Boost was not found!
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Systemd was not found, watchdog disabled!
using MSVC Compiler
Predefined unicast address: 127.0.0.1
Predefined diagnosis address: 0x00
Predefined routing application: vsomeipd
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:335 (message):
Doxygen is not installed.  Documentation can not be built.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:374 (message):
  asciidoc is not installed.  Readme can not be built.


GTEST_ROOT is not defined. For building the tests the variable
             GTEST_ROOT has to be defined. Tests can not be built.
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Desktop/BACHELORARBEIT/vsomeip/build/CMakeFiles    /CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Desktop/BACHELORARBEIT/vsomeip/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It cannot find the static Boost libraries. Now, I've tried playing around with the CMakeList.txt and here is the part of it that would be supposed to handle the linking:

```
# Boost
set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_55_0)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_55_0/stage/libs)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package( Boost 1.55 COMPONENTS system thread log REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

    if(Boost_FOUND)
      if(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR)
        MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIR not empty using it: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}" )
  else()
    if(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR)
      MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIR empty but BOOST_LIBRARYDIR is set setting Boost_LIBRARY_DIR to: ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}" )
      set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
    endif()
  endif()
else()
  MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost was not found!")
endif()
```

I have also tried using a newer boost version (1.67) with same results. Any help will be dearly appreciated!

Comment: When debug finding Boost in CMake, the first step is setting `Boost_DEBUG` variable: `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)`. It will enable debug messages which describes what exactly is searched and where.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your compiled libraries are in the following directory:

`C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_55_0/stage/libs`

If not, set your lib folder directory path:

`set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR path_to_lib_directory)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Tsyvarev suggested I used set(Boost_DEBUG ON) to trace the exact locations and files that CMake was looking for and the discovered several problems:

1.) Setting the path to "*C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_55_0*"
 causes problems, because of the space in the path

2.) It searched for the libraries covering multiple formats like:
 *boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_55.lib*.
However, when I built boost with incorrect parameters, so my libs were built like this:
*libboost_thread-vc-mt-1_55.lib*, 
which is not of the correct format.

3.) Unfortunately adding other options when building boost, e.g.:
*b2 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=32 --build-type=complete*
caused other errors. Also building boost_1_67_0 manually worked for me at all.

My solution to the problem was to simply take one of the third-party download( https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/binaries/). This way all the libraries were built correctly and I had no trouble linking to them.